# pthread multithreading in Mac OS vs windows multithreaing

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, macos

I've developed a multi platform program (using the FLTK toolkit) and implement multithreading to do background intensive tasks.

I have followed the FLTK tutorials/examples on multithreading which involve using pthread on Mac, ie the function `pthread_create` and windows threading on windows ie `_beginthread`

What I have noticed is that the performance is much higher on Windows ie 3 to 4 times faster in these background threads (in the time to execute them).

Why might this be? Is it the threading libraries I'm using? Surely there shouldn't be such a difference? Or could it be the runtime libraries underneath it all?

Here are my machine details

Mac:

Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3820QM CPU @ 2.70GHz

16 GB DDR3 1600 MHz

Model MacBookPro9,1

OS: Mac OSX 10.8.5

Windows:

Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3520M CPU @ 2.90GHz

16 GB DDR3 1600 MHz

Model: Dell Latitude E5530

OS: Windows 7 Service Pack 1

**EDIT**

To just do a basic speed comparison I compiled this on both machines running from the command line

```
int main(int agrc, char **argv)
{

    time_t t = time(NULL);
    tm* tt=localtime(&t);
    std::stringstream s;
    s<< std::setfill('0')<<std::setw(2)<<tt->tm_mday<<"/"<<std::setw(2)<<tt->tm_mon+1<<"/"<< std::setw(4)<<tt->tm_year+1900<<" "<< std::setw(2)<<tt->tm_hour<<":"<<std::setw(2)<<tt->tm_min<<":"<<std::setw(2)<<tt->tm_sec;      

    std::cout<<"1: "<<s.str()<<std::endl;

    double sum=0;

    for (int i=0;i<100000000;i++){
        double ii=i*0.123456789;
        sum=sum+sin(ii)*cos(ii);
    }


    t = time(NULL);
    tt=localtime(&t);
    s.str("");
    s<< std::setfill('0')<<std::setw(2)<<tt->tm_mday<<"/"<<std::setw(2)<<tt->tm_mon+1<<"/"<< std::setw(4)<<tt->tm_year+1900<<" "<< std::setw(2)<<tt->tm_hour<<":"<<std::setw(2)<<tt->tm_min<<":"<<std::setw(2)<<tt->tm_sec;

    std::cout<<"2: "<<s.str()<<std::endl;


}
```

Windows takes less than a second. Mac takes 4/5 seconds. Any ideas?

On Mac I'm compiling with g++, with visual studio 2013 on windows.

**SECOND EDIT**

if I change the line

```
std::cout<<"2: "<<s.str()<<std::endl;
```

to

```
std::cout<<"2: "<<s.str()<<" "<<sum<<std::endl;
```

Then all of a sudden Windows takes a little bit longer...

This makes me think that the whole thing might be compiler optimisation. So the question would be is g++ (4.2 is the version I have) worse at optimisation or do I need to provide additional flags?

**THIRD(!) AND FINAL EDIT**

I can report that I achieve comparable performance by ensuring g++ optimisation flags `-O` were provided at compile time. One of those annoying things that happens so often

A: Im tearing my hair out on problem x

B: Are you sure you're not doing y?

A: That works, why is this information not plastered all over the place and in every tutorial on problem x on the web?

B: Did you read the manual?

A: No, if I completely read the manual for every single bit of code/program I used I would never actually get round to doing anything...

Meh.

Comment: I'd be inclined to blame the pthread implementation on your mac. You could consider running a similar test on a linux, which I'd expect to have good pthread performance.

Comment: Tested it, marginally faster on linux, but still much faster on Windows. Anything I can do about it?

Comment: Can't help, sorry. The question is a bit wide open, to be honest... a minimal compilable example might help, but it is drifting a bit outside of the scope of SO. Is there are library code that you call in your thread worker routines that might be to blame?

Comment: Can you share the benchmark code?

Comment: Understood. There are no library routines, no. At the moment it is impractical to produce the code (it is large), I might produce a minimal compilable example if I get a chance, but the code I'm talking about is *exactly* the same across machines/implementations.

Comment: See edit: I think it may not be to do with multithreading...